# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

There has been lot of issues on this but i am following the exact procedure to solve this issue as described in the other related S.O questions yet i get the same error.

**Shop**

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
        //->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Product**

```
public function shop()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Shop');    
        //->withTimestamps();
    }
```

This is how my schema looks like

```
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('product_id');
                $table->integer('shop_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
                $table->foreign('shop_id')->references('id')->on('shops');

                 $table->timestamps();
);
```

**Controller**

```
$products = new Product(array(
            'name' => $request->('name');
        ));

        $shop->products()->save($products);
```

After submitting my form data into the products table, i get an error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'`. Laravel by default seems to take `id` by default as my primary key but then it is `product_id`.

In my model, i have specified `protected $primaryKey = 'product_id'` and it wouldn't solve my problem. What am i doing differently ?

Comment: could you show the query you are doing in the controller?

Comment: `products` table doesn't have `id` column, it has `product_id`. `->where('product_id', '=', ...)` and not `->where('id', '=', ...)`

Comment: @RusbenGuzman updated... shops to products is a one to many relation

Comment: @ljubadr what are you writing in the comment section of my question please?

Comment: Add this to the model `protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';`. Laravel expects `id`

Comment: Look for a definition under Primary Keys [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-models)

Comment: @ljubadr, cmon blood. Read the S.O question. I said i already had  this `protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';` .. Are you spamming the page?

Comment: in the relation of your shops model specified the name of the primary key of products? something like this, **return $ this->hasMany('App\Product', 'product_id');**

Comment: @Amateur, no spamming, I just missed that, looking at this from my phone

Comment: @RusbenGuzman i am getting another error " **Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product_product_id'"** in my `pivot table`

Comment: Could you show the models? I suppose something out there should be wrong, in the controller everything looks good

Comment: @RusbenGuzman, model for each updated

Answer (score 1):

In the relationships you have to specify the name of the primary key when it is not called id, try to change the model like this:

**SHOP**

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'product_id');
        //->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**PRODUCT**

```
public function shop()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Shop', 'product_id');    
        //->withTimestamps();
    }
```

In the documentation explains how it works:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Do you have the name of the table specified in the model?

Comment: Yes...    `protected $table = 'shops' and`    `protected $table = 'products` specified respectively

Answer (score 0):

If you are using resoure routes, then you need to specify the route key name as well:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'product_id';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had tried with my local with following:

Schema:

```
Schema::create('shops', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('product_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('shop_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('shop_id')->references('id')->on('shops');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Model relationship exactly same as your post.

Controller code:

```
$shop = new Shop;
$shop->name = 'test';
$shop->save();

$products = new Product;
$products->name = 'test';

$shop->products()->save($products);
```

And final result? It is saved into products table without error.
I am using Laravel 5.4 at my local.

When it stated `Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'` but does it stated is products table? Can you show the full Sql error log?

I suspect it might be other relationship caused the error.

Comment: i changed product_id simply to id and it is working at the moment

Comment: Did you try `public $primaryKey = 'product_id'` instead of protected?

Comment: No i didn't try it but i will give a try and let you know